# Django - Type Error Matching query does not exist

Tags: django, typeerror

Currently experiencing something very strange.

Though, I've got a plain-vanilla function & template, I receive a TypeError that refers to a line in my views.py belonging to a different function / template...

views.py:

```
def shopping(request):
 shops = Shop.objects.all()
 return render(request, 'home/shops.html', {'shops':shops})
```

shops.html:

```
{% extends 'base_template.html' %}

{% block content%}

<h2> Welcome </h2>

{{ shops }}

{% endblock%}
```

Error:

```
DoesNotExist at /home/shops/

Shop matching query does not exist.
shopdetail = Shop.objects.get(slug=shopslug)  ---> belongs to a different function
```

Comment: You should post the function that the error is pointing to it

Comment: Check your URL configuration; the URL entered is matched to the function where the error happens (whether this is intended or not).

Comment: Post your URLs file as well.

Comment: ok guys. I've solved it. Apparently it had to do with the sequence in which my urls were listed in urls.py... Anyone that can explain to what I should pay attention in the future?